# can any one tell me how to find xpath for "Use QR Code" button

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

Can any one tell me how to find xpath for "Use QR Code" button.

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try driver.findElement(By.tagName("android.widget.Button"));

Answer (score 0):

In this instance where there appears to be only one button you would do something like:

```
findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button")
```

You could also do it by class name which would find and use the first button:

```
findElementByClassName("android.widget.Button")
```

If the element's 'resource-id' attribute was set it could be:

```
findElementById("someID")
```

If the element's 'content-desc' attribute was set it could be:

```
findElementByAccessibilityId("someContentDesc")
```